# What is the difference between ForkJoinPool.commonPool() and new ForkJoinPool(availableCPU - 1)?

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

In my code, I have a class containing a static final variable

```
private static final ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(availableCPUs - 1);
```

I have a long running task submitted to the pool, which would take all the CPU resource. Any other tasks submitted would be hanging.
However, when I switched to create a common pool

```
private static final ForkJoinPool pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
```

All the tasks can be submitted and executed.

I was just wondering what the differences are between these two pieces of code. `commonPool()` still calls `new ForkJoinPool()` and passes the `availableCPUs - 1`

Also I noticed that `commonPool()` uses a factory of type `SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` while `new ForkJoinPool()` uses `ForkJoinPool$DefaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`. Does this matter?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

ForkJoin maintains two types of queues: one general inbound queue and worker thread queues for each worker thread. All worker threads will fetch from the general inbound queue first and populate their worker threads. After one worker thread finishes all the tasks in its worker queue, it will try to steal from other worker threads. If there no other task to steal from other worker threads, the work thread will fetch from the general inbound queue again.

However, with common pool, the main thread will also help to process the tasks. The main thread does not have a worker queue though. Therefore, after finishing one task, the main thread will be able to fetch from general inbound queue.

Since by default, the ForkJoin queues are LIFO, the main thread will be able the fetch the last submitted tasks.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) says:

> The common pool is by default constructed with default parameters.

> [**`ForkJoinPool()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool--)
>
> Creates a `ForkJoinPool` with parallelism equal to [`Runtime.availableProcessors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--), using the [default thread factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory), no UncaughtExceptionHandler, and non-async LIFO processing mode.

So what makes you think that `new ForkJoinPool(availableCPUs - 1)` and `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` would be pools of the same size?

If you only have 2 CPUs, then `availableCPUs - 1` means you're creating a pool of 1 thread, i.e. it can only process one task at a time, so a long-running task will block all other tasks.

But with 2 CPUs, `availableProcessors()` means you're getting a common pool with 2 threads, i.e. it can process other tasks while a single long-running task is being processed.

Comment: If you look at the source code of ForkJoinPool.java makeCommonPool() method, you will notice it is actually using availableCPUs - 1 to create the common pool. Also my initial code used ForkJoinPool() with no parameters and it had the same issue.